# How can I make dynamic parameter on the url?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, url, parameters

My url like this :

```
https://my-website.com/api/players?countryId=1&clubId=2&playerName=abc
```

The parameter is dynamic

My code like this :

```
getDataPlayer(payload) {
    let params
    if(payload.countryId && payload.clubId && payload.playerName)
      params = `countryId=${payload.countryId}&clubId=${payload.clubId}&playerName=${payload.playerName}`

    return axios.get(`https://my-website.com/api/players?${params}`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
},
```

If I console.log(payload), the result like this :

```
{countryId: "1", clubId: "2", playerName: "ronaldo"}
```

It's dynamic. The payload can be :

`{countryId: "1", clubId: "2"}` or

```
{playerName: "ronaldo"}
```

Is there a simple way? or I have to make a lot of conditions in method getDataPlayer

Answer (score 2):

For query string parameter, you can use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the string correctly.
Use `Array.map` to loop over the keys and combine final result by `Array.join` like this

```
 let params = Object.keys(payload).map(el => `${el}=${encodeURIComponent(payload[el])}`).join('&')
```

If your `payload` is `{countryId: "1", clubId: "2", playerName: "ronal do "}` the params become `"countryId=1&clubId=2&playerName=ronal%20do%20"` and it is passed to request correctly

Comment: I had try it. But it make call ajax non stop

Comment: Remove return at the line axios

Comment: I need the `return`

Comment: I think the function to format the payload to make it becomes query string correctly like the answer above is also good and maybe solve the problem. I am not sure. but logically, my code already solve the query string as your need

Answer (score 0):

If you so wish, you can use the npm module `query-string`. Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string.

You can then convert a JSON object directly into well formed search params. It provides functionality to encode as well.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function formatQuery(payload) {
  var params = '';

  if (payload.countryId && payload.countryId.trim().length) params += `countryId=${encodeURIComponent(payload.countryId.trim())}&`;

  if (payload.clubId && payload.clubId.trim().length) params += `clubId=${encodeURIComponent(payload.clubId.trim())}&`;

  if (payload.playerName && payload.playerName.trim().length) params += `playerName=${encodeURIComponent(payload.playerName.trim())}`;


  console.log(params);
  return params;

}

formatQuery({countryId: "1", clubId: "2", playerName: "ronaldo"});

formatQuery({countryId: "1", clubId: "2"});

formatQuery({playerName: "ronaldo"});
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering code-only. Remember that you are not answering only to the OP, but also to future visitors who may stumble upon this question. Do [edit] the answer to contain some explanation, either as comments in the code, or as text around it.